# MS Dynamics 4.0: Checking whether record exists based on email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm having trouble with a method that needs to return the GUID of a record based a given email address.  This is what I have at the moment:

```
        ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();
        columnSet.AddColumns(new[] { "leadid" });

        var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "lead",
            ColumnSet = columnSet
        };

        FilterExpression leadFilter = new FilterExpression();
        leadFilter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression
        {
            AttributeName = "emailaddress1",
            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
            Values = new object[] { emailAddress }
        });

        query.Criteria = leadFilter;

        BusinessEntityCollection result = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        foreach (BusinessEntity record in result)
        {
            //Guid leadId = ?? Not sure how to extract it. 
        }
```

A) this seems like overkill, because I only need one record (but don't think I can use Retrieve because I don't have an id).
B) How do I actually retrieve the GUID from the above within the foreach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) There's no guarantee that you'll only get one entity back, it might be the case, for example, that there are multiple leads with the same email address.

B) You can cast the `BusinessEntity` to the entitype you queried for, it's the abstract base class for all the other entitytypes.